# Concerns wiring Ethernet in House

Tags: wiring, ethernet

So im about to be wiring up cat6 around my house. Probably around 8 lines, and 3 drops total (leaving to floating for Cameras for outdoor).

So I have 2 Spots Im debating on, both in my office. One would be right next to the Cable Modem, which is convenient, however the Joists above it don't leave much room:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Jkr.jpg (The spot would be above the white pipe, somewhere closer to the black coax cables going down).

Pro's to this Spot:

1. It has a Beam going Vertically that would be a great spot to mount the cables to
2. It's right next to an outlet and the coax outlet

Con's:

1. Not a lot of real estate above the wall where it would go (As you can see venting is right above it too.
2. Everything would be out in the open in the office (Going to be having a kid so this is more scary

The other option is in the Closet within the office:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwmzt.jpg (Where the small brown/white wire is coming out, the joist next to it is where i'd drill down)

Pro's:

1. Hidden away in the closet which keeps it less cluttered in my office
2. Very open spot around the area for drilling/cables, actually closer to the drops I'll be doing.
3. More protected from a wandering kid. And probably better for resale (I'll have a cable passthrough which won't look bad...but still
4. As I expand my gear it's less of a problem as far as clutter (Since it'll all be in the closet)

Con's:

1. No outlets in the closet, and running them seems pointless and would need to pay someone
2. Because of the above i'll need to run 2 cables out of the closet door (Which is not far, maybe 10 feet total to the coax cable and outlet (Any suggestions on hiding it?)
3. No vertical beam to attach to (Which isn't THAT big of a deal, but I could always just create some sort of makeshift beam I suppose too, suggestions?)

Any ideas? Im leaning towards the closet, since it'll just be less messy, but I hate the idea of 2 cables coming out the closet door.

Sidenote: Any suggestion for how big of a hole I should drill for 8+ cables to be going into? (I don't want to mess with the structural integrity of the house)

Comment: Cables should pass thru a hole cut in drywall....it's not structural.    Unless absolutely necessary... never cut large holes in beams without checking with a structural engineer.    I use these to pass my cat6 into the walls in bundles

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fosmon-Opening-Passthrough-Voltage-Installation/dp/B01N1V0UK9/ref=asc_df_B01N1V0UK9/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167139094796&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3512949391848262645&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012103&hvtargid=pla-362661925127&psc=1

Comment: I need to route them to the attic, so I have to drill through the wood joists at the top. Im using something similar to what you posted to get the cables behind the drywall...but to get up the attic you have to drill through wood unless you go through the ceiling (which is unsightly). I won't be drilling a hole more than 3/4 an inch.

Comment: If you put the network hub in the closet, that along with the security system, might generate some heat, make sure to provide adequate ventilation to allow them to stay cool.

Comment: Seems like a subjective question doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put it in the closet and put an outlet in there as well.  8 wires coming out of the wall is quite messy and having this in your office behind your desk is quite unsightly and hard to organize.

I'd suggest drilling down through the top plate and running both power and the network drops down into the closet wall.  I would use separate holes for the cat6 and power to keep them apart.  Mount a 1/4 inch sheet of plywood on the wall to the studs, this gives you the freedom to mount the network switch wherever you want and gives you a better handle on cable management.  Sand and paint it if you want it to look good.

WRT the coax.  You can either keep the cable modem at the desk and run an ethernet port to the office desk or, as you suggested, put it in the closet.  I would opt for the closet, but instead of running the coax under the door, I'd run that in the wall as well.  You seem to have good access in the attic, so you have the freedom to run an extra cable.  I'd go up from the box where the existing cable is, connecting them with a barrel, and run the new cable into the closet.

No cables on the floor, no bundle of wires coming out into the office.

Remember to seal the holes you drill into the top plate with fire rated caulk after running the wires through them.